# Why HashMap internal work helper variables are int, which can be byte datatype

Tags: java, variables, hashmap, int, byte

HashMap internally has its own static final variables for its working.

```
        static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;
```

Why can't they use `byte` datatype instead of using `int` since the value is too small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `byte` or `short` for variables and constants instead of `int` is a premature optimization that has next to no effect.

Most arithmetic and logical instructions of the JVM work only with `int`, `long`, `float` and `double`, other data types have to be cast to (usually) `int`s in order for these instructions to be executed on them.

The default type of number literals is `int` for integral and `double` for floating point numbers. Using `byte`, `short` and `float` types can thus cause some subtle programming bugs and generally worsens code readability.

A little example from the [Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/) book:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (byte b = Byte.MIN_VALUE; b < Byte.MAX_VALUE; b++) {
        if (b == 0x90)
            System.out.print("Joy!");
    }
}
```

This program **doesn't** print `Joy!`, because the hex value `0x90` is implicitly promoted to an `int` with the value `144`. Since `byte`s in Java are signed (which itself is very inconvenient), the variable `b` is never assigned to this value (`Byte.MAX_VALUE = 127`) and therefore, the condition is never satisfied.

All in all, the reduction of the memory footprint is simply too small (next to none) to justify such micro-optimisation. Generally, explicit numeric types of different size are not necessary and suitable for higher level programming. I personally think that only case where smaller numeric types are acceptable are byte arrays.

Answer (score 5):

They could, but it would be a micro-optimization, and the tradeoff would be less readable and maintainable code ([Premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), anyone?).

This is a static final variable, so it's allocated only once per classloader. I'd say we can spare those 3 (I'm guessing here) bytes.

Comment: I personally think that the question doesn't fall under the category of premature optimization. It's a pretty valid question as to why something which can be represented as a `byte` was declared as an `int`.

Comment: No, that's totally a premature optimization.  (Additionally, because of alignment constraints, I'm not even convinced that writing it as a `byte` _would_ save any memory at all.)

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: I know all that and hence my answer. My point is, from the point of view of a beginner, it doesn't help him if all we say is "that's premature optimization, let's not bother with that". Also, I'm *not* talking about saving memory but using the right data type for the job. We need to explain it to him *why* `byte` wasn't chosen rather than just saying "premature optimization" and washing our hands clean.

Comment: I'm not convinced of that, though.  "Premature optimization is bad" is a perfectly good reason not to do this change _on its own_, and it's a lesson worth learning for beginners.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is because the capacity for a `Map` is expressed in terms of an `int`. When you try to work with a `byte` and an `int`, because of promotion rules, the byte will anyways be converted to an `int`. The default capacity is expressed in terms of an `int` to maybe avoid those needless promotions.

Answer (score 2):

The byte values still taking the same space in the JVM and it will also need to be converted to int to the practical purposes explicitly or implicitly, including array sizes, indexes, etc.

Comment: int consumes 4 byte and byte consumes a byte for storing its values

Comment: @krishna, it's JVM dependent, but most JVMs store int, short, byte and boolean internally as a 32-bit word, mainly to keep it word aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Converting from a `byte` to an int`(as it needs to be an`int` in any case) would make the code slower if anything. The cost of memory is pretty trivial in the overall scheme of things.

Given the default could be any `int` value, I think `int` makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of data can be represented as a series of Bytes.

Int is the default data type that most users will use when counting or workign with whole numbers.

the issue with using Byte is that the compiler will not recognize it for type conversion.

anytime you tried

```
int variablename = bytevariable;
```

it wouldnt complete the assignment however

```
double variablename = intVariable;
```

would work.